# Nothing shown at back end of joomla admin control panel

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-template, joomla2.5

[image]

When I have logged in the backend administration section of joomla its showing as such why is it so??

I am totally confused seeing this...

Is this any error

or Any plugin issue...

The site has been Upgraded from 1.7 to 2.5 a month ago.. 
But then also any hint of such a problem was not seen....

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine had this issue and I helped him narrow it down.

This problem is caused by fiddling with **_viewlevels** table in your joomla database. Some plugins/extensions could possibly make such changes as well.

In Joomla Content is classified by who can view/access it. There are three levels of Content Access Classification:

- Public - open to all visitors to the web site.
- Registered - restricted to all seven Registered User Groups of the web site.
- Special - restricted to all User Groups except Guest and Registered.

Administrator belongs to Special. Giving Special all permissions solves thee problem. For some reason, Special class no longer had the ability to access menus of administrator panel in your application.

Edit the **Special** entry in **viewlevels** table so it looks like this:

```
      id           title           ordering        rules             
|-------------|----------------|-------------|----------------| 
| 3           | Special        | 2           |[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]|   
|-------------|----------------|-------------|----------------|
```

Sources:
[Users: Access Control Levels - Joomla documentation](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/228/153/1/2/)

Comment: dude you just saved my life! @afaf12